# HTML position messages in order

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript method for loading the messages in a mini chat app. The idea is that I have two HTML classes to position the message either on left or right depending on who sent it. The HTML and CSS are fine and work properly. My question is when it comes down to getting the messages from Firestore.

I have the following messages in order from first sent to last: `Hello, hyd?, Good, Hello Sir, hey`

[image]

But somehow strangely they are not ordered properly when displayed on the screen, I get first the messages sent from other user then it displays my messages. I am not sure where I messed up the code for this behavior but I somehow believe it has to do with the `if` statement where I check who sent the message. The document of a message in Firestore has the following structure:

```
{
   createdAt: ....,
   message: ....,
   from: ....,
   to: ....
}
```

```
     let divMessagesLeft = document.getElementById("firstmessages--main-div-id");
     let devMessagesRight = document.getElementById("firstmessages--main-div-id-2");

     async function loadMessages() {
       firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function (user) {
         if (user) {
             let messagesReference = firebase
             .firestore()
             .doc(`/chats/${user.displayName}`)
             .collection(`/chats/${userChat.username}/messages`)
             .orderBy("createdAt");

           await messagesReference
             .get()
             .then(function (snapshot) {
               snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                 console.log(doc.data().message);
                 if (doc.data().from === userChat.username || doc.data().to === user.displayName) {
                   const message = `<div class="messagee">${doc.data().message}</div>`;
                   divMessagesLeft.innerHTML += message;
                 } else {
                   const message = `<div class="messagee messagee-right">${doc.data().message}</div>`;
                   devMessagesRight.innerHTML += message;
                 }
               });
             });
         } else {
           console.log("Not logged in");
         }
       });
     }
     loadMessages();
```

```
          <div id="chat-messages-main-div-id" class="chat-messages-main-div">
            
            <div id="first-message-div-id" class="first-message-div">
              <div id="firstmessages--main-div-id" class="firstmessages--main-div">
                <!-- <div class="messagee">Hello</div> -->
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="first-message-right-id-2" class="first-message-right">
              <div id="firstmessages--main-div-id-2" class="firstmessages--main-div">
                <!-- <div class="messagee messagee-right">Hi</div> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to replace the "||" operator with "&&", which is a more correct check to do.
(it will fail if you'll try messaging yourself, and you should think how you want to implement this scenario).

Also I think you need to add "desc" to the "order by" method.